# Why did Jessica not believe the tape which mentioned her rape?

Tags: plot-explanation, 13-reasons-why

In the series **13 Reasons Why**, *Jessica* had her place on Tape 2.

She must have obviously heard all the tapes long back.

Must have even heard *Justin*'s second tape.

Considering all these, why didn't she believe it? Why did she still chose to hang around with *Bryce* even more?

Comment: A combination of denial and a longing for normalcy, contributed to Jessica not [initially] believing Hannah's tape, as well as her wanting to continue to hang around with Bryce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Jessica trusts Justin Foley way more then Hannah Baker. And Justin Foley lied to her and made her believe Hannah is liar and remember that many of other people from tape tried to prove Hannah liar too.

So who will Jessica trust, her boyfriend or a dead girl she had bad tuning with? Easy choice, boyfriend.